# Problem with date formats in JavaScript with different browsers

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-format, date-parsing

I am working with dates in an RSS feed, but am finding differing results when using the code below in IE, Chrome and Firefox:

```
new Date('2001-01-01T12:00:00Z')
```

Firefox is happy with that, but Chrome and IE return Invalid Date.

I thought I'd try replacing the T and Z as follows:

```
new Date('2001-01-01 12:00:00')
```

This time Chrome is happy with that, but Firefox and IE return Invalid Date.

Any ideas what I should do to get a date object in all browsers with this format?!

Many thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This works in all browsers on my box - try it in the console:

```
alert(new Date('2001/01/31 12:00:00'))
```

so

```
new Date('2001-01-01T12:00:00Z'.replace(/\-/g,'\/').replace(/[T|Z]/g,' '))
```

IE8, FF3.6, Safari4, Chrome

Comment: You're right, this works, and it's a better solution than mine.

Comment: Many thanks! Tested and working for me in IE, FF, Chrome and Opera!

Comment: How do I make this work on FF with timezone? Because this `new Date('2001-01-01T12:00:00+1000'.replace(/\-/g,'\/').replace(/[T|Z]/g,' '))` return Invalid date in FF, but works in IE/Chrome

Comment: new Date('2001-01-01T12:00:00+1000') works fine in Fx, Chrome

Answer (score 3):

Can you try:

```
new Date(2001,0,1,12,0,0)
```

This means:

```
new Date(year,month,day,hour,minutes,seconds)
```

Comment: You mean

new Date(2001,0,1,12,0,0)

since JS months start with 0

Comment: Be careful with leading 0s. 08 and 09 are invalid octal numbers

Answer (score 3):

You could also try using [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) - an open source javascript date manipulation library.

Comment: Also momentjs (www.momentjs.com) hammers out browser discrepancies.

Answer (score 3):

This works on all of the major 5 browsers and causes all browsers to recognize the time as GMT/UTC rather than local time (the Z suffix means the time is UTC):

```
new Date('2001-01-01T12:00:00Z'.replace(/\-/g,'\/').replace(/T/,' ').replace(/Z/,' -0'))
```

I thank mplungjan for his answer.