# Javascript using datejs to parse RFC3339 datetime

Tags: javascript, datetime, date, datejs

I'm having trouble using datajs with a date format from Google Calendar API. The datetime format I believe is RFC3339 and this is a sample datetime returned from the calendar api

```
2012-01-05T08:45:00Z
```

This is from the datejs documentation [here](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/)

```
Date.parse('1985-04-12T23:20:50Z')          // RFC 3339 Formats
```

But this just returns null.

I'm assuming I have datejs working correctly as

```
Date.today().next().friday()
```

returns Fri May 11 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)

Comment: What browser and browser version you use? IE7-8? `Date.parse('1985-04-12T23:20:50Z')` return `NaN` in IE7-8. In FF correct value returned.

Comment: @AndrewD. I'm using the JavaScript console in Chrome

Comment: @mplungjan thanks but that doesn't help as I want to use datejs and datejs should be able to use 1985-04-12T23:20:50Z. If you go to datejs.com you can enter a date on their website and it will work fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SOLVED**: Use Date.parseExact OR [this version](http://datejs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/build/date-en-US.js) according to this [Bug report](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=rfc&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=147)

[DEMO using date.js](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/x2APB/)

[DEMO using date-en-US.js](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/X6dYe/)

---

Using the first version I get

```
null
http://datejs.googlecode.com/files/date.js
Line 13
```

when I take the assertions out of the [testsuite](http://www.datejs.com/test/date_and_time/index.html):

```
// null
console.log('Date.parse("1985-04-12T23:20:50Z")',
  Date.parse('1985-04-12T23:20:50Z'));


// my previous answer works
console.log('Date.parse("1985-04-12T23:20:50Z".replace(...))',
     Date.parse('1985-04-12T23:20:50Z'
           .replace(/\-/g,'\/')
           .replace(/[T|Z]/g,' ')
     )
  );

// the test suite without the Z works
console.log('1985-04-12T23:20:50',
  new Date(1985,3,12,23,20,50).equals( Date.parse('1985-04-12T23:20:50')));

// but this one fails when not in the test suite    
try {
  console.log('1985-04-12T23:20:50Z',
    new Date(1985,3,12,23,20,50).equals( Date.parse('1985-04-12T23:20:50Z')));
}
catch(e) {
     console.log('1985-04-12T23:20:50Z',e.message);
}
```

Here is an [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566125/problem-with-date-formats-in-javascript-with-different-browsers) for this issue when not using date.js

Comment: It seems that Date.parseExact("1985-04-12T23:20:50Z", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") works ok.

Comment: According to http://www.datejs.com/test/date_and_time/index.html Its Much faster with Date.parseExact("1985-04-12T23:20:50Z", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")

Comment: So either use the above version or use parseExact. I do not think speed is an issue here.