# C3.js - How to specify the timestamp format when plotting timeseries taken from InfluxDB

Tags: timestamp, format, time-series, c3.js, influxdb

influxDB timestamps look like this:

- `2015-01-29T21:55:43.702900257Z`

The question is what options should I use for the `x-axis` when I generate the graph with C3.js

The error I get:

> *"Failed to parse x '2015-01-29T21:55:43.702900257Z' to Date object"*

Maybe this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsrdzszg/) will help you do some quick tests... I think the problem is with the time format but any other suggestions are welcome:

```
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'timeseries',
        tick: {
            format: '%Y-%m-%d'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: InfluxDB emits RFC3339 timestamps. A quick search shows a [few](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531276/javascript-using-datejs-to-parse-rfc3339-datetime) [recommendations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318634/how-to-convert-date-in-rfc-3339-to-the-javascript-date-objectmilliseconds-since) for parsing RFC3339 timestamps in javascript.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, I had to add `xFormat` because as [@das Keks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016386/das-keks) says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642089/c3-js-timeseries-with-time-fails-to-parse):

> *"The format in the axis Object just defines how the date will be displayed. **If you want to specify the format for the date parsing you have to use xFormat** in the data object."*

```
data: {
    x: 'x',
    xFormat: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ',
    columns: [
        ['x', ... ],
        ['data1', ... ]
    ]
}
```

For the `xFormat options` see D3.js / [Time Formatting](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format)

---

Second, to get to the right format, I changed every timestamp by first creating a Date object with `Date()` and then by using `dateObj.toISOString()`. For example, open your console and try this:

```
> new Date('2015-09-30T12:21:41.447494312Z').toISOString();
> "2015-09-30T12:21:41.447Z"
```