# C3 xFormat is not working for timestamp in seconds

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

First of all, there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32950521/4802664) and I also read GitHub issues related to xFormat & timestamp (i.e. [here](https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/805)). None of these solved my problem.

From [D3 Time Format](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format) :

> %Q - milliseconds since UNIX epoch.
>   %s - seconds since UNIX epoch.

When using `xFormat: '%Q'` and timestamp in milliseconds (i.e. 1524362421000), it is working.

**But when using `xFormat: '%s'` and timestamp in seconds (i.e. 1524362421) all tick marks along x-axis showing wrong date: `1970-01-18`)**

```
axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'timeseries',
      tick: {
          fit: true,
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          rotate: 45
     }
}
```

[Here is the JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4tq165m/78/)

The JSON response from API uses timestamp in seconds and I can not change it to milliseconds (I know JS uses milliseconds to parse date). Therefore, I need `xFormat: '%s'` to work.

Comment: xFormat: '%s' works on c3js.org website. Did you check you are using both the last versions of c3js and d3.js?

Comment: @Sala did you check my JS fiddle in the question? It didn't work in fiddle and my dev PC (offline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually whats going on with your code is that xFormat is not doing anything with your format strings - it formats directly the strings when you're not using the tick formatter. You can remove it and it will still work with millis because its the **"type":"timeseries"** argument from tick that is doing all the magic. But, as you said, we can work on a solution with a d3.js time formatter. As a solution, you could replace your xAxisSettings with this:

```
var xAxisSetting = {
  //type: 'timeseries',
  tick: {
    fit: true,
    format:function (x) {
        var formatSeconds = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d")
        return formatSeconds(new Date(x*1000)); },
    count: 8,
    rotate: 45
  },
  label: {
    text: 'Date',
    position: 'outer-center'
  },
  //min: xMin,
  //max: xMax,
  padding: {
    left: 0,
    right: 0
  },
  height: 70
};
```

What we did here:

- We commented out the type timeseries as we are doing our own time formatting (don't forget to import d3-time and d3-time-format to your project). If you don't remove this line, it will format as a date and it will not remain as a timestamp for us to do our own formatting stuff.
- The format now has a function where the argument x is the seconds string that is coming from your json object. We are simply writting the d3 simple seconds formatter inside the function.
- The formatter needs a date as a parameter, so we create one as pass the milliseconds (seconds * 1000)

[You can see it working here](https://jsfiddle.net/o4tq165m/114/). Hope it meets your expectations.

Comment: It worked. Glad that you mentioned `"type":"timeseries"` issue (didn't know it)