# Using same code for chrome and firefox but get different results

Tags: javascript

I have a simple count down script. The code works in chrome but not firefox. In firefox it displays NaN but chrome shows the countdown any ideas why this happens?

```
function CountDownTimer(time, name) {
  var counter = setInterval(function(){
    var today = new Date();
    var expire = new Date(time);
    var timeRemains = expire - today;

    var days  = Math.floor(timeRemains / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor(timeRemains / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var mins  = Math.floor(timeRemains / (1000 * 60));
    var secs  = Math.floor(timeRemains / 1000);

    var dd = days;
    var hh = hours - days  * 24;
    var mm = mins  - hours * 60;
    var ss = secs  - mins  * 60;

    if (expire < today) {
      clearInterval(counter);
      document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = '<span class="expire">expire!</span>';
      return;
    } else {
         if (dd < 10) {
             dd = "0" + dd;
         }
         if (hh < 10) {
             hh = "0" + hh;
         }
         if (mm < 10) {
             mm = "0" + mm;
         }
         if (ss < 10) {
             ss = "0" + ss;
         }
         document.getElementById(name).innerHTML = dd + ' : ' + hh + ' : ' + mm + ' : ' + ss;
    }
  }, 1000 );
}


CountDownTimer("2012-07-06 19:00:00", "Time1");​
```

Comment: `<font color="red"></font>`??? Use `<span>` instead!

Comment: console log says time is not defined?

Comment: _time_ seems like a questionable name for a variable to me...

Comment: @Mr.1.0 - Try `var today = +new Date();var expire = +new Date(time);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Date() function doesn't seem to work well across all browsers. Try using setUTC functions on it, like so:

```
today.setUTCFullYear(2012);
today.setUTCHours(19, 0, 0, 0);
```

UPDATE: Date() constructor fine on all browsers, just not when an "improper" string is used. Try this:

```
var today = new Date(2012,6,7,19,0,0)
```

Comment: how do i make it work with the function? i tried `CountDownTimer("2012,6,7,19,0,0,", "test");` and without quotes but still returns `NaN`

Comment: @Cameron Lattz - It *should* work well across all browsers because it is the standard format. See [MDN for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/#Example:_Several_ways_to_assign_dates).

Comment: @Derek: Yes, it does work well on all browsers. At first, I mistakenly spoke from personal recollection. I edited my answer. Also, there might be a string format that works cross-browser, but depending on how he plans to use his function (seems like he wants to allow a user to input their own date and time), the Date() constructor which takes integers as parameters, or the setUTC functions, is probably the optimal solution.

Comment: @Mr. 1.0: You will have to change 3 lines of your code, like this: `function CountDownTimer(y, mo, d, h, mi, s, name) {`, then `var today = new Date(y,mo,d,h,mi,s);`, and `CountDownTimer(2012,6,7,19,0,0, "Time1");`

Answer (score 2):

Change the date format for something like this:

```
CountDownTimer("June 7, 2012 19:00:00", "Time1");​
```

Comment: it says expired for any date i add

Comment: @Leo - Um... If it works on Google Chrome, then probably that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` stands for not a number.

If Leo's suggestion doesn't help, it's probably worth adding a few sporadic `console.log()`'s into the mix to find out where the problem is.

Comment: did you seriously just grammar nazi me?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the new Date() format, which is not consistent across browsers.

[Problem with date formats in JavaScript with different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566125/problem-with-date-formats-in-javascript-with-different-browsers).

You can likely make it work by converting the - chars to /.  Cameron's answer should provide good cross-browser behaviour, otherwise consider using a 3rd party library such as moment.js

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802861/javascript-date-manipulation-library