# Displaying the just date not time part in jquery dataTable but sorting on both date and timepart?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datetime, datatables

i am sending the date as string from server as explained below which has both date and time part like 2010-12-07 17:35:04.127.
what i want is just display the date not the time part in data table column i.e 2010-12-07. But also i want  the sorting happens
on complete date including the time part. So customer created  at 2010-12-07 18:35:04.12 should be displayed above
2010-12-07 17:35:04.12 in dataTable column. here is my specific date column code snippet in datatable

```
  "aoColumns": [ { "mDataProp": "customerCreated","bSearchable": false,
                           "fnRender": function ( o, val  ) 
                               {
                               var javascriptDate = new Date(o.aData["customerCreated"]);
                               javascriptDate = javascriptDate.getFullYear()+"/"+javascriptDate.getMonth()+"/"+javascriptDate.getDate();
                               return "<div class= date>"+javascriptDate+"<div>";
                               }

                       } ]
```

Issues i am facing are:-

1)On IE and Mozilla date is displayed as NaN/NaN/NaN. **Not getting why?**

2)On Chrome date is displayed but month is displayed decremented by 1.**Why javascriptDate.getMonth() return month decremented by 1?**

**3)i am not sure sorting will work if take above route where i am displaying just date part but want sorting to happen on complete date including date part?**

FYI
i am using the bserverSide as false .Basically i am getting the data from server in one go and do the sorting on client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS months start with 0 and the date needs / instead of -

Related to [Problem with date formats in JavaScript with different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3566222/295783)

Try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/YRKLt/)

```
function getFormattedDate(dString) {
  var d = new Date(dString.split(".")[0].replace(/-/g,"/")); // assuming 2010-12-07 17:35:04.127
  var mm = d.getMonth()+1;
  var dd = d.getDate();
  if (mm<10)mm="0"+mm;
  if (dd<10)dd="0"+dd;
  return d.getFullYear()+"/"+mm+"/"+dd;
}

"aoColumns": [ { "mDataProp": "customerCreated","bSearchable": false,
  "fnRender": function ( o, val  ) {
    return "<div class= date>"+getFormattedDate(o.aData["customerCreated"])+"<div>";
  }
} ]
```

If you need the time too it would be

```
function getFormattedDate(dString) {
  var d = new Date(dString.split(".")[0].replace(/-/g,"/")); // assuming 2010-12-07 17:35:04.127
  var mm = d.getMonth()+1;
  var dd = d.getDate();
  if (mm<10)mm="0"+mm;
  if (dd<10)dd="0"+dd;
  var hh = d.getHours();
  var min = d.getMinutes();
  if (hh<10) hh="0"+hh;
  if (min<10) min="0"+min;
  return d.getFullYear()+"/"+mm+"/"+dd+" "+hh+":"+min;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mplungjan. Regarding date display it works great. But sorting does not happen correctly. I mean customer created at 2010-12-07 17:35:04.12 displayed in datatable  above of  customer created afterwards i.e at 2010-12-07 18:20:02.16. i mean sorting does not work for the customer created on same date.Looks like it is happening becoz we removed the timepart from date. Is there a solution where i can just display the date excluding time part but sorting happens based on date and time?

Comment: I do not know how the column sorts. We can add the time