# Converting Javascript String to Datetime

Tags: javascript

I have a text box that is populated from a datepicker in Javascript.  The date is stored as `30-Jan-2013`.  I want to convert this to a date so I can use it in other calculations.

I have tried

```
var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById('textbox').value)
```

but this returns `Nan`

if I drop the `new Date` part e.g.

```
var date1 = (document.getElementById('textbox').value
```

I get the date `30-Jan-2013` I just don't seem to be able to convert this?

Comment: Are you trying to parse the date using JavaScript or ASP.NET?

Comment: What browser are you using?   In Chrome `new Date('30-Jan-2013')` works for me.  Regardless, the format needs to be one supported by `Date.parse`, as documented in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: something is wrong, because that code not suppose to return Nan, just try var date = new Date("30-Jan-2013") it will return "Wed Jan 30 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (WET)". so, on time when you call this code your textbox doesn't have a value

Comment: @VadimIvanov That's only if you use Chrome. This will blow up on Firefox (and possibly other browsers). The constructor calls the parse method, which has implementation-dependent behavior. The best bet is to manually parse the date and feed the constructor integer arguments. Or alternatively feed it a universally recognized [ISO 8601 date.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Here's a fiddle running through some date formats (strings) and converting them to Date objects. Results vary by browser. Good luck! http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/MgdQa/

Comment: Check out [Problem with date formats in JavaScript with different browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3566125/781965)

Comment: You have a *datepicker* script that does not return a `Date` object? Or at least has an output option to return a reusable format?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses,  I am using IE and I want the code in JS.  Vadim, maybe I do not unserstand but I do not want to pass a hard coded date in as the date is picked by the user and it is not necessarily going to be todays date?

Comment: I have the same problem. and i have  datepicker script that does not return a Date object. So how to fixed it @Bergi

Comment: works only for chrome

Comment: @JoyAcharya Manually parse the output, or use a different date picker library.

Comment: @Bergi thanks i have solved it already . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `Date.parse` is not going to work because the format the datepicker is returning.

You might want to look at the following thread for parsing solutions or change your format that the datepicker outputs to one of the supported formats.

[How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript)

http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/03/javascript-and-dates-what-mess.html

Useful parse info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: The only useful information on that MSDN page is "*… is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 standards mode and Quirks mode*"

Comment: Thanks Jeff, your link has given me the answer!  This works using parseDate(date1)

Comment: var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById('textbox').value)

Comment: Sorry my mistake it was the link provided by kelsey to a blog from Rafael Mueller that gave me the answer!  How can I convert string to datetime with format specification in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to recommend you a simple, easy to use and fast library `[moment.js][1]`

```
moment("30-Jan-2013").format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

will return "January 30th 2013, 12:00:00 am"

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will work for your problem**

```
  var date= document.getElementById('textbox').value.split("-");;
  var date1 = new Date(date[2] + " " + date[1]  + " " + date[0]);
  date1 .toLocaleDateString("en-GB");
```