# what is wrong with this date format

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, datetime, cross-browser

This works in Chrome but not in Firefox.

```
new Date("2013-06-03 17:09:06-0400")
```

- Works fine in Chrome
- Gives 'NaN' in Firefox.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Related / similar question with solution (no real answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566125/problem-with-date-formats-in-javascript-with-different-browsers

Comment: The accepted answer in that question does not work for my case. I tried using: new Date('2013-06-03 17:09:06-0400'.replace(/\-/g,'\/').replace(/[T|Z]/g,' ')) but it gave 'Invalid date'.

Comment: No worries. Answer from @benastan worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) for better parsing support.

Comment: I did. It looks great. Thanks for the suggestion. Especially since I was trying to use it for a very similar purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Mozilla Developer Network's [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2Fparse) documentation.

Specifically, it states:

> Alternatively, the date/time string may be in ISO 8601 format. Starting with JavaScript 1.8.5 (Firefox 4), a subset of ISO 8601 is supported. For example, "2011-10-10" (just date) or "2011-10-10T14:48:00" (date and time) can be passed and parsed.

If you throw a 'T' in between the date and the time you get:

```
new Date("2013-06-03T17:09:06-0400")
=> Mon Jun 03 2013 14:09:06 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

In both Chrome and Mozilla, although you have to account for the the current timezone (thus PDT) of the user's system.

Comment: Awesome. Adding the 'T' does the magic. Works in both Firefox and Chrome now. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the *only* reliable way to construct a date object from a string in JavaScript is to parse the string yourself, and then use the version of the constructor that takes a separate numeric parameter for each field.

The string-based constructor is far too prone to issues with locale-related parsing errors.

Comment: Thanks for your response as well. I appreciate the advice.